# Is it possible to have as a adapter an FragmentStateAdapter, which will display different data for 3 different fragments?

Tags: java, android, api, mvvm, android-recyclerview

In short - I'd like to ask, if it is possible to use the FragmentStateAdapter for let's say 3 fragments, but every single one has it own RecyclerView, so every single one will need different data to display. For now, I've just setup some basic TabLayout for these fragments, but Im not sure how would it work.

Comment: Yes its possible . in fact that's the reason we have `ViewPager` widget .

Comment: @ADM So in order to use it, I have to implement own adapter for every fragment class?

Comment: No. . just follow some ViewPager2 tutiri ..

Comment: @ADM such an informative response! thank you